# How to convert a regular font to a UI font?

Tags: fonts, font-design, android

I have an Android device and its language is Arabic. I want to replace its font with my own one (which is nicer!), but the default font for Arabic in Android is NotoNaskhArabicUI (which is a UI font; see [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80240/noto-sans-vs-noto-sans-ui?newreg=be5dd8a6eb85429685b52cc764248cdc) for example).

If I simply put my desired font in the action, in buttons, the text is clipped.

How can I convert a regular TTF font to a UI font so it has stricter vertical boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Font Squirrel webfont generator: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
It converts your uloaded font into woff and woff2 format, which later can be used with @font-face in CSS like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'noto_sans_arabic_uiregular';
    src: url('notosansarabicui-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('notosansarabicui-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any font converter?? Like https://lvgl.io/tools/fontconverter